# FreeSwitch ESL: NodeJS/JS/Freeswitch Syntax Confliction

Tags: node.js, api, events, syntax, freeswitch

I'm building a Twillio-like Dialer API using Modesl in Node.JS to send commands and parameters to Freeswitch Console.

Edit: I've narrowed down the issue to a syntax issue, where the javascript I'm using to input my variables are conflicting with FreeSwitchs syntax. 
**uuid_send_dtmf** needs to have a ' in front of it, whereas uuid is a NodeJS parameter that needs to be passed after one space, as is dmtf, and the api_on_answer requires a ' for closing after my parameters are passed.

Syntax has always been my weak point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
,api_on_answer='uuid_send_dtmf ' + uuid  + ' ' + dmtf +' ' }
```

```
    conn.api('originate {
                  origination_uuid=' + uuid 
                  + ',origination_caller_id_number=' + cid 
                  + ',api_on_answer=uuid_send_dtmf ' + uuid  
                  + ' ' + dmtf +' }
              sofia/external/' + pnumber + '@provider', function(res) {
```

Currently the command is giving a very vague error of little help:

> 2019-03-17 08:53:22.755065 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2204 Parsing global variables
>   2019-03-17 08:53:22.755065 [ERR] switch_ivr_originate.c:2209 Parse Error!
>   2019-03-17 08:53:22.755065 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3941 Originate Resulted in Error Cause: 27 [DESTINATION_OUT_OF_ORDER]

What is the correct way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using '\' to input ' inline.

var onanswer = '\'' + uuid + ' ' + dmtf;

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
conn.api(`originate {origination_uuid=${uuid},origination_caller_id_number=${cid},api_on_answer='${uuid_send_dtmf} ${uuid} ${dtmf}'}sofia/external/${pnumber}@${provider}`, function(res) {
```

template literals or strings, enclosed by back-ticks, this would provide you the required format,  cheers :)